# Subquery value bigger than another subquery value

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I've got a query which returns 8 columns, 2 of them are sub queries which returns the maximum date. I would like to create 9th column which will return a number, asterisk  or something to highlight the rows where date in column 1 is bigger than in column 2 but still keep all the rows. Is it possible somehow?

Edit:
this is the query
The columns I want to see the differences in are MaxExpDateGB and MaxExpDatePH

```
select
i.ITEM,
i.COMPANY,
count(distinct i.LOGISTICS_UNIT) as LocationsGB,
sum(on_hand_qty) as StockGB,
(select
Count(distinct location)
from
LOCATION_INVENTORY b where b.ITEM = i.ITEM and b.TEMPLATE_FIELD1 = '139' and b.TEMPLATE_FIELD4 is not null and b.TEMPLATE_FIELD5 is null) as LocationsPH,
(select
sum(on_hand_qty)
from
LOCATION_INVENTORY b where b.ITEM = i.ITEM and b.TEMPLATE_FIELD1 = '139' and b.TEMPLATE_FIELD4 is not null and b.TEMPLATE_FIELD5 is null) as StockPH,
MAX(i.Expiration_DATE) as MaxExpDateGB,
(select
MAX(a.Expiration_DATE)
from
LOCATION_INVENTORY a where a.ITEM = i.ITEM and a.TEMPLATE_FIELD1 = '139' and a.TEMPLATE_FIELD4 is not null and a.INVENTORY_STS = 'available' ) as MaxExpDatePH
from
LOCATION l inner join LOCATION_INVENTORY i on l.LOCATION = i.LOCATION inner join ITEM t on i.ITEM = t.ITEM
where
t.USER_DEF6 = '10'
and i.LOCATION = '000-gb-01'
group by
i.item,i.company
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can use a case expression with most DBMS systems today.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  The answer to your question is "yes, it is possible, somehow".  Any more than that is impossible to add, because your question lacks relevant information.

Comment: Show your query and it will be easier for us to help. And please tag your request with the DBMS you are using (PostgreSQL, Oracle, ...).

Comment: Okay let's play it your way. How can I put an asterisk at the end of each row when column 1 value bigger then column 2 value and these columns are subqueries? Added the query, Columns 1 and 2 are MaxExpDateGB and MaxExpDatePH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any refactoring

```
select *, case when LocationsPH > StockPH then '*' end flag
from (
    select
        i.ITEM,
        i.COMPANY,
        count(distinct i.LOGISTICS_UNIT) as LocationsGB,
        sum(on_hand_qty) as StockGB,
        (select
            Count(distinct location)
            from
            LOCATION_INVENTORY b where b.ITEM = i.ITEM and b.TEMPLATE_FIELD1 = '139' and b.TEMPLATE_FIELD4 is not null and b.TEMPLATE_FIELD5 is null
        ) as LocationsPH,
        (select
            sum(on_hand_qty)
            from
            LOCATION_INVENTORY b where b.ITEM = i.ITEM and b.TEMPLATE_FIELD1 = '139' and b.TEMPLATE_FIELD4 is not null and b.TEMPLATE_FIELD5 is null
        ) as StockPH,
        MAX(i.Expiration_DATE) as MaxExpDateGB,
        (select
            MAX(a.Expiration_DATE)
            from
            LOCATION_INVENTORY a where a.ITEM = i.ITEM and a.TEMPLATE_FIELD1 = '139' and a.TEMPLATE_FIELD4 is not null and a.INVENTORY_STS = 'available' 
        ) as MaxExpDatePH
    from
    LOCATION l 
    inner join LOCATION_INVENTORY i on l.LOCATION = i.LOCATION inner join ITEM t on i.ITEM = t.ITEM
    where
    t.USER_DEF6 = '10'
    and i.LOCATION = '000-gb-01'
    group by
    i.item,i.company
) t
```